# проблема умного фильтра в битрикс

Tags: javascript, ajax, битрикс

Господа, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Есть битрикс. На нем есть smart.filter, который мгновенно применяет изменения и фильтрует товар при выборе опции, поэтому, выбрав одну опцию, исчезают другие (фильтрует на ходу). Нужно сделать так, чтобы этот смарт фильтр не делал ничего до нажатия на кнопку применяющую фильтр.

Comment: AJAX_MODE = "N"  
"INSTANT_RELOAD" => "Y"
у вас?

Comment: ХОТЬ УБЕЙТЕ, не вижу строки INSTANT_RELOAD, AJAX_MODE="Y"

Comment: можете показать ваш вызов компонента в таком виде? http://joxi.ru/5mdBG5otvvE8aA

Comment: проблема в том, что он идет вместе с custom.catalog и как такового вызова его как отдельной функции нет...ситуация из ряда "он вроде бы и есть, но вроде бы его и нет."

Comment: давайте перейдем в режим чата? где вам будет удобно общаться?

Comment: https://vk.com/alex_hatefeeld вот здесь

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте! Честно говоря тоже не наблюдаю  AJAX_MODE... может не туда смотрю конечно?! Подскажите, куда копать?

```
    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog.smart.filter",
    "filter-3",
    Array(
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "visual_vertical",
        "CONVERT_CURRENCY" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_ELEMENT_COUNT" => "N",
        "FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
        "FILTER_VIEW_MODE" => "vertical",
        "HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "9",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
        "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => "arrPager",
        "POPUP_POSITION" => "right",
        "PRICE_CODE" => array(0=>"BASE",),
        "SAVE_IN_SESSION" => "N",
        "SECTION_CODE" => "",
        "SECTION_CODE_PATH" => "",
        "SECTION_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "SECTION_ID" => "",
        "SECTION_TITLE" => "-",
        "SEF_MODE" => "N",
        "SEF_RULE" => "",
        "SMART_FILTER_PATH" => "",
        "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
        "XML_EXPORT" => "N"
    )
);?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
"INSTANT_RELOAD" => "N",
```